# Defining two get function in WebAPI

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

I am getting to following exception when i am trying to call a GET function in MVC WebAPI

```
 {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.",
 "ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
 \r\nSystem.Xml.XmlNode Get(Int32, System.String)
```

I think the problem is cause due to two get function
I have defined two functions:

**One:**

```
   [HttpGet]
   public XmlNode Get(int id, string Tokken)
   {
        //Do something
   }
```

**Second One**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public List<UsersAnswers> GetUsersInteractions(int? activityID, string Tokken)
 {
  // Do Something
 }
```

**The route configuration**

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now i am getting the exception when i try to call to the second function:

```
{SiteURL}/api/Activities/GetUsersInteractions?activityID=32&Tokken=r54e54353
```

As you can see the route engine sent the request to the first function instead of the second.

How can i define two get operation and to call each one separately?

Comment: One is a GET, the other one is a POST, not 2 GET's ... did you paste the wrong code?

Comment: Yep i pasted the wrong code by mistake. i have edited the questions. thanks

Comment: Please post the route configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the default routing template, Web API uses the HTTP method to select the action. However, you can also create a route where the action name is included in the URI:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In this route template, the {action} parameter names the action method on the controller. With this style of routing, use attributes to specify the allowed HTTP methods. For example, suppose your controller has the following method:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Details(int id);
}
```

In this case, a GET request for “api/products/details/1” would map to the Details method. This style of routing is similar to ASP.NET MVC, and may be appropriate for an RPC-style API.

You can override the action name by using the ActionName attribute. In the following example, there are two actions that map to "api/products/thumbnail/id. One supports GET and the other supports POST:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Thumbnail")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetThumbnailImage(int id);

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Thumbnail")]
    public void AddThumbnailImage(int id);
}
```

Comment: I have added the attribute ActionName but it still not working it still trow the same exception

Comment: Is it executing the MapHttpRoute? Maybe try removing all other action methods except the 2 we are talking about ...

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the second function - the second function is named `InsertUserRecord` and is a `POST` method. The function you're calling via `GET` is `GetUserInteractions`. As there's no such function for `GET`, the engine may map this to the only `GET` function there is, but actually it should throw a "no such function" error.

Comment: But he is not getting "no such function". Most likely, the problem is something else. You posted your answer prematurely.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I wrote an answer to the question as it was - now the situation has changed, and while my answer is now no longer fully correct, it was valid for the "first version" of the question :-)