# defining two get functions in Odata web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have similar question as [Defining two get function in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567945/defining-two-get-function-in-webapi)

I have created an ODataController  , which has two get method with same signature except the data type of parameter.

One method take Id as key and return language object.

Second method take string name and return language object.

```
[EnableQuery]
    
public SingleResult<Language> GetLanguage([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(_LanguageService.GetById_Queryable(key));
}

[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Language> GetLanguage([FromODataUri] string lname)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(_LanguageService.GetByName(lname));
}
```

Results:

First Method: `http://localhost/RoomReservationSystem_Api/odata/Languages(1)`

```
{
    "@odata.context":"http://localhost/RoomReservationSystem_Api/odata/$metadata#Languages/$entity","Name":"Urdu","Enabled":true,"Id":1
}
```

Second Method: `http://localhost/RoomReservationSystem_Api/odata/Languages(%22Urdu%22)`

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Can you show us the BuildFunctions method?

Comment: I have not added any definition in Build Function for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, OData Lib can't understand your second method call:

http://localhost/RoomReservationSystem_Api/odata/Languages(%22Urdu%22)

Because `Language` type only has the int as its key.

If you do want to make it work, I think you can use a new feature named alternate key shipped in ODL 6.13.

Here's the alternate key sample: https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataAlternateKeySamples

Hope it can help you. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/WebApi/v4/ODataAlternateKeySamples/ODataAlternateKeySamples/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs     Why edm model is generatd in  WebApiConfig instead of Startup.Auth class, I have use same sample but now it is not displaying any content .. http://localhost/RoomReservationSystem_Api/odata/ApplyAts this is giving HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Comment: In AlternateKeysDataSource Class, this sample is     'using public static EdmEntityObjectCollection Customers { get; private set; } '....